# Bokeh CustomJS load javascript classes

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, bokeh

I am making standalone HTML objects, and I would like to know how to use more commands than the ones like Math.sin(), etc, when using CustomJS. Ideally I would like to use flexx to write my callback in python language, and pass an array created with numpy to the callback. My immediate concern is the inclusion of complex numbers, and my more general direction would involve fft code.

In a jupyter notebook, using Python 3, I can run the following:

```
#created by Kyle Johnston
import numpy as np

from ipywidgets import interact

from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, save
from bokeh.models.layouts import Row, Column, WidgetBox
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, push_notebook, save, file_html, output_file
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot,layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS, Range1d, Slider
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4

################## Defintions #########################################

c= 3e8
IR = 2000e-9
VIS = 2000e-9
t = np.linspace(-200.*1e-15,200.*1e-15,2000)

E_IR=1; w_IR= c*2*np.pi/IR; tau_IR= 70.*1e-15
E_VIS=1; w_VIS= c*2*np.pi/VIS; tau_VIS= 6*1e-15
E_field_IR = E_IR*np.exp(1j*t*w_IR)*np.exp(-2*np.log(2)*(t/tau_IR)**2)
E_field_VIS = E_VIS*np.exp(1j*t*w_VIS)*np.exp(-2*np.log(2)*(t/tau_VIS)**2)
E_f_IR_Real = np.real(E_field_IR)
E_f_VIS_Real = np.real(E_field_VIS)

tau_1= tau_IR; w_1=w_IR;
tau_2= tau_VIS; w_2=w_VIS;
x1 = t
x2 = t
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*c*x1/IR)*np.exp(-(x1/tau_1)**2)
y2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*c*x2/IR)*np.exp(-(x1/tau_2)**2)
y3 = y1+y2
# y1 = np.sin(w_1*x1)
# y2 = np.sin(w_2*x2)
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x1=x1, y1=y1))
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x2=x2, y2=y2))
source3 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x2=x2, y3=y3))

################ Figures ##############################################
p = figure(y_range=(-5, 5), plot_width=700, plot_height=600)

p.line('x1', 'y1', source=source1, line_width=3, line_alpha=1,\
   color='green',legend='wave1')
p.line('x2', 'y2', source=source2, line_width=3, line_alpha=1,\
   color='blue',legend='wave2')
p.line('x2', 'y3', source=source3, line_width=2, line_alpha=0.5,\
   color='purple',legend='sum')


################# Callback to update figures    ##########################################

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source1=source1,source2=source2,source3=source3), code="""
    var data1 = source1.data;
    var data2 = source2.data;
    var data3 = source3.data;
    var delay = 1e-15*delay.value;
    var A1 = amp1.value;
    var k1 = wave1.value;
    var phi1 = phase1.value;
    var B1 = offset1.value;
    var tau1 = 1e-15*tau1.value;
    var A2 = amp2.value;
    var k2 = wave2.value;
    var phi2 = phase2.value;
    var B2 = offset2.value;
    var tau2 = 1e-15*tau2.value;

    x1 = data1['x1']
    y1 = data1['y1']
    x2 = data2['x2']
    y2 = data2['y2']
    y3 = data3['y3']

    for (i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
        y1[i] = B1+A1*Math.sin(phi1+3e8*2*Math.PI*(delay+x1[i])/(k1*1e-9))*Math.exp(-Math.pow((delay+x1[i])/tau1,2));
        y2[i] = B2+A2*Math.sin(phi2+3e8*2*Math.PI*x2[i]/(k2*1e-9))*Math.exp(-Math.pow(x2[i]/tau2,2));
        y3[i] = y1[i]+y2[i];
    }
    source1.change.emit();
""")



delay_slider_1 = Slider(start=-400, end=400, value=0, step=1,
                title="Delay (fs)", callback=callback)
callback.args["delay"] = delay_slider_1

amp_slider_1 = Slider(start=0.1, end=1, value=1, step=.1,
                title="Amplitude 1", callback=callback)callback.args["amp1"] = amp_slider_1

wave_slider_1 = Slider(start=700, end=3000, value=2000, step=10,
                 title="Wavelength  1 (nm)", callback=callback)
callback.args["wave1"] = wave_slider_1

phase_slider_1 = Slider(start=-10*np.pi, end=10*np.pi, value=0,    
                    step=np.pi/10, title="Phase 1", callback=callback)
callback.args["phase1"] = phase_slider_1

offset_slider_1= Slider(start=-5, end=5, value=0, step=.1,
                   title="Offset 1", callback=callback)
callback.args["offset1"] = offset_slider_1

tau_slider_1 = Slider(start=1, end=100, value=70, step=1,
                   title="tau 1 (fs)", callback=callback)
callback.args["tau1"] = tau_slider_1

######################### Wave 2 ###################################
amp_slider_2 = Slider(start=0.1, end=1, value=1, step=.1,
                title="Amplitude 2", callback=callback)
callback.args["amp2"] = amp_slider_2

wave_slider_2 = Slider(start=700, end=3000, value=2000, step=10,
                 title="Wavelength 2 (nm)", callback=callback)
callback.args["wave2"] = wave_slider_2

phase_slider_2 = Slider(start=-10*np.pi, end=10*np.pi, value=0,
                    step=np.pi/10,title="Phase 2", callback=callback)
callback.args["phase2"] = phase_slider_2

offset_slider_2 = Slider(start=-5, end=5, value=0, step=.1,
                   title="Offset 2", callback=callback)
callback.args["offset2"] = offset_slider_2

tau_slider_2 = Slider(start=1, end=100, value=5, step=1,
                   title="tau 2 (fs)", callback=callback)
callback.args["tau2"] = tau_slider_2


###################### Make Layout and activate clickable plot   #######################################
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
p.y_range=Range1d(-2.1,2.1)
p.x_range
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'time(s)'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Amplitude (arb)'


l = layout(Column(
p,WidgetBox(delay_slider_1),
Row(Column(WidgetBox(amp_slider_1, wave_slider_1, phase_slider_1, \
                     offset_slider_1, tau_slider_1)),
Column(WidgetBox(amp_slider_2, wave_slider_2, phase_slider_2,\
                 offset_slider_2, tau_slider_2)))
))

show(l)
```

and this produces a wonderful interactive plot.

You can see that I rewrote the math in the callback because I do not know how to include complex numbers  in the callback. I would like to know how to link the apache commons math package into my notebook, and/or how to create this using numpy inside the callback. As far as I can see, flexx enables python scripting inside the callback for everything EXCEPT the actual math portions. 
Is something like jpype the thing I need to use?

I hope the example above helps someone, and that someone can help me.

P.S.    Also, as this is my first ever question, I hope the working example is complete. Do I really have to go line by line and add 4 spaces, or is there a quicker way?

Comment: If you are working in a notebook, you may want to use this approach instead: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#jupyter-interactors 

It seems like a perfect fit for your use case, since you want complex interactions in your notebook that depend on Python code.

Comment: Yes, I agree that is a simple way. I am looking to create standalone HTML though.

Comment: Then you are limited to what is available to the JavaScript runtime. You might be able to use JavaScript libraries outside of the core libraries by embedinging them in the output HTML file (such as MathJS or something similar). This would be at the risk of global name collisions though and would be very painful to debug. For reference here is what is available in the `Math` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math